# Returning Value from JavaScript Function into HTML Form Input Value Attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to auto fill a form element with the current date and time in a specific format required by mySQL. My difficulty is auto-filling this value into a form element. So far I have tried using .getElementById("element_id").innherHTML = timestamp
But this does not result in any text filling the form element:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Create New Reservation</title>
<script>
function Timestamp()
{
const currentTime = new Date();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var dash = "-";
var space = " ";
var colon = ":";
var hour = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var timestamp = year.toString().concat(dash, month, dash, day, space, hour, colon, minutes, colon, seconds);
document.getElementById("occurred").innerHTML = timestamp;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Timestamp()">
<h1>Enter Reservation Details</h1>
<form method="POST" action="reservation_process.php">
<fieldset>
<label>Current Time</label><type="text"/>
<input type="text" id="occurred" name="occurred"
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Process" value="Create Entry" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried returning the formatted timestamp from the function directly into the value="" attribute, but I suspect my syntax is incorrect and I have not been able to find any HTML documentation on how to do this properly:

<input type="text" id="occurred" name="occurred" value= Timestamp() >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#occurred').val(timestamp);` instead of `document.getElementById("occurred").innerHTML = timestamp;` inside your function.

`$(element).val(value)` sets the value of an input, if you not already have you need to include `jQuery` to use this.

```js
function Timestamp(){
  const currentTime = new Date();
  var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
  var month = currentTime.getMonth();
  var day = currentTime.getDate();
  var dash = "-";
  var space = " ";
  var colon = ":";
  var hour = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  var timestamp = year.toString().concat(dash, month, dash, day, space, hour, colon, minutes, colon, seconds);
  $('#occurred').val(timestamp);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create New Reservation</title>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body onload="Timestamp()">
<h1>Enter Reservation Details</h1>
<form method="POST" action="reservation_process.php">
<fieldset>
<label>Current Time</label><type="text"/>
<input type="text" id="occurred" name="occurred"
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Process" value="Create Entry" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why jQuery??? OP just need to change `document.getElementById("occurred").innerHTML` to `document.getElementById("occurred").value`!